# Array of strings to be made from the properties of a type | Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have this type for a React Form:

```
type User = {
 fullName: string,
 username: string,
 email: string;
 password: string;
};
```

In order to render some errors coming from the API, I need to use those values to a constant named "keys".

```
const keys = Object.keys(errorsFromApi);
```

When setting the errors it indicates me the following error:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"fullName" | "username" | "email" | "password"'
```

I did a quick fix typing keys: (any) but I would like to know how can I do it properly.

Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: How about `const keys = Object.keys(errorsFromApi) as (keyof User)[];` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Object.keys` type is not very strict, so I usually end up defining my own `keys` function like so:

```
const keys = <T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>(obj: T): Array<keyof T> => 
  Object.keys(obj)
```